# How do you delete one part in the plaintext I scraped from the site?

Tags: php, string, replace, scrape

Here is the code that I used to scrape the name and the url but every name starts with `~`.
I would like to delete the `~` part. I've tried using `str_replace` but it doesn't seem right from looking at it. (also tested it and same result)

```
foreach ($div_category as &$div){
    $a_list = $div->find("a");
    foreach ( $a_list as &$anchor){
        //put the data into an array and then write array out to a csv file.
        $csv_array=array($anchor->plaintext, $anchor->getAttribute("href") );
        $anchor = str_replace( '~', ' ', $anchor);
        fputcsv($csv_out, $csv_array);
```

current result example:

```
name      url
~john     www.john.com
~bob      www.bob.com
~rob      www.rob.com
```

Comment: I hate these questions. I am a webmaster myself and I hate those  who cannot create anything of their own but only can "scrape" the fruit of my labor. And I am even supposed to help them!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$str = "~~~~~~";
$str = str_replace("~","!",$str);
echo $str;
?>
```

Works for me. So the replacing part should be fine. You must be addressing the attribute of your anchor 'incorrectly'. Try printing the anchor with:

```
print_r($anchor)
```

to see what attribute you should be using

**EDIT:**

```
foreach ($div_category as &$div){
    $a_list = $div->find("a");
    foreach ( $a_list as &$anchor){
        //put the data into an array and then write array out to a csv file.
   ->   $csv_array=array($anchor->plaintext, $anchor->getAttribute("href") ); // line X
   ->   $anchor = str_replace( '~', ' ', $anchor);                            // line Y
        fputcsv($csv_out, $csv_array);
```

The problem is the **order of the X and Y lines** marked with arrows. Switch them around and it should be working.

EDIT2:

and

```
$anchor = str_replace( '~', ' ', $anchor);
```

should be

```
$anchor->plaintext = str_replace( '~', '', $anchor->plaintext);
```

Comment: when i print_r($anchor) end of the function it only display list of the names and they are clickable(which is the url attached to it) but no symbol. But when i put ! as you suggested it would show the !john in the print out. So i seem to print them out right but in the csv file it is still showing the ~ symbol.

Comment: OK look at the edit to the answer and you should have the solution

Comment: I actually switch them around earlier and it gave me an error 
Fatal error: Call to a member function getAttribute() on a non-object
on line X part

Comment: What if you put $anchor->plaintext = str_replace( '~', ' ', $anchor->plaintext); instead, using the suggested YX ordering (see edit2)

Comment: in csv it only show one name and url (by the way it works and no ~) and the browser is stuck loading with the display simple_html_dom_node Object ( [nodetype] => 1 [tag] => a [attr] => Array ( [href] => with alot words below that instead of the usual list of names.

Comment: Sounds like the problem has been solved and that you have a new problem now. You can state the new problem in a new question :)

Comment: actually its not solved it seems the same as my original question/result. I wanted to display them in csv so i can create another function in php to read that correct csv

Comment: OK I can't handle it over the comments though